# Error: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-connection

[image][image]i have config.php to connect my database, by for long time im trying to rectify this issue, but still iam gettign connection refused, so can anyone help me to solve this issue?
i added correct db, pass, user and host aswell

my config.php

please help me solve this issue.

Comment: Please do not post code as an image, An image can be deleted over time, making the question useless. Edit you question and post it as  text.

Comment: "Connection refused" means one of two things: either there is no MySQL server listening on port 3306 on the server you're connecting to, or something is blocking the network connection between your app and the database. This could be because the MySQL server is configured to only listen to localhost connections, or there could be a firewall blocking either *incoming connections* to the MySQL server from an outside network or *outgoing connections to port 3306* from the server your PHP application is on.

Comment: It's hard to tell with the crossed out DB_HOST value in your screenshot, but from the length of that hostname and the bottoms of the last letters, it *looks* like your database is running on Amazon AWS. If that is the case, you might need to create an inbound rule for your MySQL instance.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i think you have to add port into connection line like this:

```php
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;port=3306;dbname=db", $username, $password);
```

Usually, it will be 3306

Comment: i tried with port also, but not working

Comment: Enter additional information about connection credentials. Where do you use app ? With docker or other software ?

Comment: you too dear. Please accept if my response helped you